# Hibernate: initialize vs unproxy

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having an issue with a ManyToMany

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    name = "PORTFOLIO_USER_PERMS",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PORTFOLIO_ID"), }
)
private List<Portfolio> sharedPortfolios = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have one scenario where one of the of the sharedPortfolios one element is a proxy and another element have an attribute that is a proxy (actulay is the same object because of a one-to-one relationship). This list is normally returned to a Controller method which then is converted to the respective DTO's. As you might suspect, that single attribute with a proxy object is causing a *LazyInitializationException*.

[image]

This means that in the service i need to traverse every element on the list looking for any attributes that might be a proxy and unproxy with the Hibernate Utility: *Hibernate.unproxy(...)* before it is passed to the controller.

My questions:

1) what is the difference between *Hibernate.initialize* and *Hibernate.unproxy*?

Initializing the proxy object does not fix the problem.

2) Why one of the elements is a proxy, but the others not?

3) What is there a better way then manually traverse this list and all the attributes and search for proxy objects?

Thank you so much.

Best Regards.

Comment: `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`

Comment: Thank you very much. Even it resolves the issue, it have performances issues. I dont need to have that list retrieved from Database unless it is really necessary.

Comment: How are you retrieving your entities? There are different way to tell Hibernate to eagerly fetch the relationships.  For example, using HQL: `from Foo foo join fetch foo.sharedPortfolios where blablabla`

Comment: Actually i am not using a query, just the getter for sharedPortfolios. It is hibernate that is managing the query and list creation. Should i create a method on my Spring JpaRepository?

Comment: How did you get the entity that contains the `sharedPortfolios` relationship then?  That's the place you could retrieve the relationship "when it is really necessary"

Comment: In this case is by using the respective getter. Its funny that I have never seen this behaviour from a similar method from JpaRepositry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your first question you can look at the implementation of the two methods:

```
    /**
     * Unproxies a {@link HibernateProxy}. If the proxy is uninitialized, it automatically triggers an initialization.
     * In case the supplied object is null or not a proxy, the object will be returned as-is.
     *
     * @param proxy the {@link HibernateProxy} to be unproxied
     * @return the proxy's underlying implementation object, or the supplied object otherwise
     */
    public static Object unproxy(Object proxy) {
        if ( proxy instanceof HibernateProxy ) {
            HibernateProxy hibernateProxy = (HibernateProxy) proxy;
            LazyInitializer initializer = hibernateProxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer();
            return initializer.getImplementation();
        }
        else {
            return proxy;
        }
    }
```

and

```
    /**
     * Force initialization of a proxy or persistent collection.
     * <p/>
     * Note: This only ensures initialization of a proxy object or collection;
     * it is not guaranteed that the elements INSIDE the collection will be initialized/materialized.
     *
     * @param proxy a persistable object, proxy, persistent collection or <tt>null</tt>
     * @throws HibernateException if we can't initialize the proxy at this time, eg. the <tt>Session</tt> was closed
     */
    public static void initialize(Object proxy) throws HibernateException {
        if ( proxy == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( proxy instanceof HibernateProxy ) {
            ( (HibernateProxy) proxy ).getHibernateLazyInitializer().initialize();
        }
        else if ( proxy instanceof PersistentCollection ) {
            ( (PersistentCollection) proxy ).forceInitialization();
        }
        else if ( proxy instanceof PersistentAttributeInterceptable ) {
            final PersistentAttributeInterceptable interceptable = (PersistentAttributeInterceptable) proxy;
            final PersistentAttributeInterceptor interceptor = interceptable.$$_hibernate_getInterceptor();
            if ( interceptor instanceof EnhancementAsProxyLazinessInterceptor ) {
                ( (EnhancementAsProxyLazinessInterceptor) interceptor ).forceInitialize( proxy, null );
            }
        }
    }
```

For instances of entity proxies (`HibernateProxy`) the two methods do essentially the same, with the only difference that `unproxy` returnes the unproxied entity.
From my testing so far, it should not make a difference whether you work with the return value or the original reference.

`initialize` also works for persistent collections (`PersistentCollection`). When you need to initialize a ToMany-Relation, like in your question, you will need to use this method.

> Initializing the proxy object does not fix the problem.

You need to initialize the collection `sharedPortfolios`, not just object that contains the collection:

```
Hibernate.initialize(entity.sharedPortfolios)
```

Alternatively, you might want to `JOIN FETCH` the relation in the query or use an entity graph to avoid having to initialize afterwards and to avoid the extra queries.

Comment: Do you have any clue why this one element of the collection was still a HibernateProxy while others weren't? Also `Hibernate.initialize(entity.getList())` did not do the trick for me. But join fetch did, which is nicer anyway I believe, thank you!

Comment: One reason that the other elements were not a proxy could be, if they were already loaded in the Hibernate Session (first-level cache). I'm not entirely sure, but I believe, Hibernate will get the entities from first-level cache, or return a proxy when accessing a lazy property, similar to how the `Session.load` method works.

Comment: And yes, I'd also say that join fetch is nicer than `Hibernate.initialize`.

Comment: It is possible that the other entities were referenced in another entity I just had in my persistence context